# MVVM approved method for disabling certain characters in textbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Is there a way to disable certain characters from being written into a wpf textbox without using code in the code behind file?

I have a few int fields that are bound to text boxes that I would like to limit to keys 0-9 only. If I enter anything else I do get the red validation error but that is not enough.

Comment: Probably the best way is to create a `Behavior<TextBox>`.  Eg: http://www.julmar.com/blog/programming/numerictextboxbehavior-wsa/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using [`IDataErrorInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.idataerrorinfo%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for WPF validation since WPF already understands how to use it, and its easy to implement.

You have to add the interface on your class, and the required methods will look like this:

```
#region IDataErrorInfo Members

public string Error
{
    get { return null; }
}

public string this[string columnName]
{
    get
    {
        if (columnName == "YourProperty")
        {
            int property = Convert.ToInt32(YourProperty);
            if (property < 0 || property > 9)
                return "The value must be between 0 and 9";
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }
}

#endregion
```

Next, you need to set `ValidatesOnDataErrors=True` in your TextBox binding so it runs the validation whenever the property changes.

When something has gone wrong, it adds a red border on your control and the message you put on your validation:

[image: Error message]

You can read more about how to use the interface:

- [WPF: Validation made easy with IDataErrorInfo](http://codeblitz.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/wpf-validation-made-easy-with-idataerrorinfo/)
- [Really simple WPF form data validation - how to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20495619/really-simple-wpf-form-data-validation-how-to)

Answer (score 1):

In fact, this  task is not possible enterily in xaml.

At some point, you need to write some code.

These are some links could be useful

http://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/08/26/data-validation-in-wpf/
http://soumya.wordpress.com/2010/05/09/wpf-simplified-part-15-data-validation/