# WPF- validation rule deep understanding

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, validation, datagrid

so i have a `datagrid`in WPF based on `datasource`. i created a class `ValidationRule` to validate all `datagrid` data. now for error styling u i use the `RowValidationErrorTemplate` with the path: `Path=(Validation.Errors)/ErrorContent}` now- if i want to enable/disable a button  based on if theirs error or no- in that page- how could i refer to the `(Validation.Errors)` to check if its not empty? i tried using `Validation.HasError` but it was always `false` even when the `datagrid` did have wrong validation- any one?

Comment: Are you implementing `IDataErrorInfo` to do your validation? That is the standard for WPF. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20509923/302677) for more information.

Comment: no- im implementing **ValidationRule** instead

Comment: Assuming your button is not in the data grid and it is binded to some different property, the button would not disable because the datagrid's binding is failing and not button's.
Can you share code snippet of your xaml.
Ideally you need to disable button by referring to your data grid in a button's Style Trigger.

Comment: Check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509541/disabling-button-on-validation-error

Comment: @DasDas I believe XAML's `Validation.Errors` uses the `IDataErrorInterface`, so if you want to use that kind of syntax in your XAML you should implement `IDataErrorInfo` for your validation instead. ValidationRules are more for WinForms than WPF.

Comment: @Rachel but my datagrid is bind to a datasource not a class object