# Show UserControl as invalid when DependencyProperty is invalid

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, user-controls

I have user control which works as a vendor selector. It displays the currently selected vendor name and uses a button to display a vendor selection dialog.

```
    <PO:VendorSelector VendorId="{Binding Path=VendorId, Mode=TwoWay,
 ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True}" />
```

I use ValidationAttributes on the data model to check if VendorId is null. Note that no control within the usercontrol binds directly to VendorId.

When I call Validator.TryValidateObject the null VendorId message is generated, but the user control never shows any error indications. I need to show the whole user control in error.

What do I need to do? What am I missing?

The standard "Red Border/Tooltip" Validation template is reused from one which works for text boxes.

Comment: I would recommend switching to using the `IDataErrorInterface`, since WPF uses that interface for validation purposes. You can see a really simple example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20509923/302677), which includes a customized validation template.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the custom validation attribute I was using had omitted to set the optional MemberNames parameter on the call to new ValidationResult(string Message, string[] MemberNames). This resulted in the error being dropped from the Linq aggregate query in HandleValidationResults lines 75-78 in the validation code I am using originally from

http://www.eidias.com/Blog/2013/7/13/utilizing-inotifydataerrorinfo-in-wpf-mvvm-app

Once the member name array was passed everything worked fine.