# Show validation text in separate control

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, xaml

I have a property, bound to a `TextBox`, which is only allowed to be a positive number (i.e. `x > 0`). Inspired by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20495619/really-simple-wpf-form-data-validation-how-to) I have decided to implement this using [IDataErrorInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.idataerrorinfo(v=vs.100).aspx) interface.

Following the instructions in that post, I can get a tool-tip warning to show, if the input cannot be validated. But I would like to have the validation warning shown in a seperate `TextBlock`, just below the input `TextBox`.

**XAML:**

```
<!-- ValidatingControl Style -->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type FrameworkElement}" x:Key="ValidatingControl">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding 
                Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent, 
                RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}}" />  
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

(...)

<TextBlock Text="Product price:" />
<TextBox
    Name="Price"
    DataContext="{Binding SelectedProduct}"
    Style="{StaticResource ValidatingControl}"
    Text="{Binding Path=Price, 
            StringFormat=N0, 
            ConverterCulture=da-DK, 
            Mode=TwoWay,
            ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>

<!-- This should contain validation warning -->
<TextBlock Margin="0 0 0 10" />
```

**Binding property (C#):**

```
public class ProductModel : IDataErrorInfo
{

    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    (...)

    // Implementation of IDataErrorInfo
    string IDataErrorInfo.Error
    {
        get { return null; }
    }

    string IDataErrorInfo.this[string columnName]
    {
        get
    {
            if (columnName == "Price")
            {
                // Validate property and return a string if there is an error
                if (Price < 0)
                    return "Cannot be negative.";
            }

            // If there's no error, null gets returned
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind your textblock to IDataError interfaces indexer property.

Here modified code

```
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Product price:" />
        <TextBox  Name="Price" Text="{Binding Path=Price, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>

        <!-- This should contain validation warning -->
        <TextBlock Margin="0 0 0 10" Text="{Binding [Price]}" />
    </StackPanel>
```

Also you need to do some modifications to your view model.

```
    class ViewModel : IDataErrorInfo, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        decimal _price;
        public decimal Price
        {
            get => _price;
            set
            {
                _price = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Price));
                RaisePropertyChanged("Item[]");
            }
        }

        // Implementation of IDataErrorInfo
        string IDataErrorInfo.Error
        {
            get { return null; }
        }

        public string this[string columnName]
        {
            get
            {
                if (columnName == "Price")
                {
                    // Validate property and return a string if there is an error
                    if (Price < 0)
                        return "Cannot be negative.";
                }

                // If there's no error, null gets returned
                return null;
            }
        }

        void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

Note, that indexer property for IDataErrorInfo interface is implemented implicitly, otherwise WPF system for some reason can't bind to it.
Also take a look to the INotifyPropertyChanged interface implementation for Price property, especially on the `RaisePropertyChanged("Item[]");` line. Without this line WPF's system binding system will not know, if there is an error.

Comment: Actually I have implemented `IDataErrorInfo` in my model (not my view model), like the example I followed. I have updated my code to show this. `INotifyPropertyChanged` in implemented in my view model and seems to work fine. If I add `{Binding [Price]}`, then I get a run time warning that the binding could not be made, because the property does not exist.

Comment: As i mentioned in answer, you need implicit implementation of IDataErrorInfo interface's indexer property. This will fix binding warning.

Comment: Your model should also implement INotifyPropertyChanged to inform view about validation indexer property changes. Or you can move/incapsulate data validation logic to/in ViewModel.

Comment: thank you, I got it to work now. I missed the fact, that you had a different implementation of `this[string columnName]`.

Comment: @GorRustamyan: Why did you copy my answer?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the indexer as *public* property, implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and raise a change notification for the indexer when the `Price` property is set. This should work:

```
public class ProductModel : IDataErrorInfo, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private decimal _price;
    public decimal Price
    {
        get { return _price; }
        set
        {
            _price = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Item[]");
        }
    }

    string IDataErrorInfo.Error
    {
        get { return null; }
    }

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            if (columnName == "Price")
            {
                // Validate property and return a string if there is an error
                if (Price < 0)
                    return "Cannot be negative.";
            }

            // If there's no error, null gets returned
            return null;
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<!-- This should contain validation warning -->
<TextBlock DataContext="{Binding SelectedProduct}" Margin="0 0 0 10" Text="{Binding [Price]}" />
```