# Access Editing Cell of DataGrid in C# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I made a Datagrid with XAML:

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGridBlockRow" Width="Auto" AutoGenerateColumns="False" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False" 
  CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="false" CanUserDeleteRows="false" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
  BeginningEdit="dataGridBlockRow_BeginningEdit"
  LoadingRow="gridColumns_LoadingRow" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Row Number" MinWidth="120" Width="1*">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Margin="0" Text="{Binding Path=RowNumber}">
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <toolkit:UIntegerUpDown Name="InputNumber" Value="{Binding Path=RowNumber, Mode=TwoWay}" AllowTextInput="False">
                    </toolkit:UIntegerUpDown>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Tree Count" MinWidth="120" Width="1*">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Margin="0" Text="{Binding Path=TreeCount}">
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <toolkit:UIntegerUpDown Name="inputTree" Value="{Binding Path=TreeCount, Mode=TwoWay}">
                    </toolkit:UIntegerUpDown>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

[image]

in c# code I added a List to my DataGrid:

```
List<BlockRow> blockRowList = new List<BlockRow>(); 
dataGridBlockRow.ItemsSource = blockRowList;
```

I want to Access the input control `InputNumber` and `InputTree`.
How can I access the current Editing Cell Input TextBox?

Comment: Does this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20495619/really-simple-wpf-form-data-validation-how-to

Comment: MS also shows you this example - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-implement-binding-validation?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: I want to access the input control of editing cell. @MauricioGraciaGutierrez

Comment: what do you mean accessit ? get a object reference to the control and use its properties ?

Comment: Yes i need a reference

Comment: @MustafaPoya: From where and when do you want to access the input controls and why? There are probably better ways of doing whatever you're trying to do.

Comment: When I am trying to edit a cell of row @mm8

Comment: In what event handler?

Answer (score 0):

In WPF better to avoid change controls inside DataTemplate.
But if you want to get reference you can use FindName method of dataTemplate.

```
public static Control GetControlFromCellEditingTemplate(this DataGridColumn column, string controlName)
{
   DataTemplate template = column.CellEditingTemplate;   
   return template.FindName(controlName, column);
}
```

you can use it like

```
var inputNumberUpDown = ((DataGridColumn)dataGridBlockRow.Columns[0]).GetControlFromCellEditingTemplate("InputNumber") as UIntegerUpDown;
var inputTreeUpDown = ((DataGridColumn)dataGridBlockRow.Columns[1]).GetControlFromCellEditingTemplate("inputTree") as UIntegerUpDown;
```